# getting message in a command from the discord chat

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have this line which needs to recieve a message from the discord text channel.

```
choice = video[int.Parse(CommandHandler.message .Content)-1].Url;
```

I tried a lot of things, including searching in the api but I don't have a clue.

Here is the command

```
[Command("join", RunMode= RunMode.Async), Summary("joins voice channel")]
public async Task joinvoice([Remainder, Summary("The text to echo")] string searchP="")
{

    IVoiceChannel voicechannel = (CommandHandler.Last as IGuildUser).VoiceChannel;

    if (voicechannel == null)
    {
        await ReplyAsync("u have to be in a channel first");
        return;

    }
    string choice = "";
    VideoSearch SearchRisolts = new VideoSearch();
    if (searchP != "")
    {
        if (searchP.Contains("https://"))
            choice = searchP;
        else
        {
            List<VideoInformation> video = SearchRisolts.SearchQuery(searchP, 1);
            await ReplyAsync("1) " + video[0].Title + "\n\n2) " + video[1].Title + "\n\n3) " + video[2].Title);

            choice = video[int.Parse(CommandHandler.message .Content)-1].Url;//here i need to recive a message from the chat
        }
    }

    if (voicechannel != Program.voicechannel)
    {
        Program.audioClient = await voicechannel.ConnectAsync();
        Program.voicechannel = voicechannel;

    }
    if (Program.audioClient!=null)
        await SendAsync(Program.audioClient, choice);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class containing this function should derive from `BaseModule<ICommandContext>`

This *BaseModule* contains the Context, which in place contains the message you are looking for.

```
Context.Message.Content
```